# Path for the transpiler in WebStorm

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass, webstorm

I'm new to scss and trying to set this whole thing up...

I've installed ruby and now have the command line for it (I'm on Windows).
Also ran the gem install sass command.

Now I need to specify a path under program for the transpiler, to get the watcher to work and translate the scss files to css.

The guidelines on the JetBrains website say - "Specify a path variable for the folder where the Ruby executable file and the gem.bat file are stored. This lets you launch Ruby and Gem Manager from any folder and ensures that Ruby is successfully launched during transpilation"

I don't understand where and what are the Ruby exectuable file and the supposedly gem.bat that I need to input in that field.

[image: watcher]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be `<Ruby installation dir>/bin/scss.bat`, like `C:\Ruby193\bin\scss.bat`